# no matching function for call to 'TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(std::_cxx11::string&)

Tags: c++, tinyxml

```
    for (int i = g, x=0; i < counter - 1 && x < 99; i++,x++){
std::string point = std::to_string(i);
std::string pointx = std::to_string(point_vec[i].x);
std::string pointy= std::to_string(point_vec[i].y);

TiXmlElement* P = new TiXmlElement( point );
TiXmlText* X = new TiXmlText(pointx);
doc.LinkEndChild(X);
TiXmlText* Y = new TiXmlText(pointy);
doc.LinkEndChild(Y);
doc.LinkEndChild(P);
}
```

Above is my example code which I am trying to work on right now, my issue is that it tells me the following:

"error: no matching function for call to 'TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(std::_cxx11::string&)"  this is using wxwidgets on c++, the idea behind using tinyxml is to be able to store the arrays and reuse them after.

Solvved this : I had to go into tinyxml.h and add this at the top : #define TIXML_USE_STL

Comment: Try `new TiXmlElement( point.c_str() )` instead.

Comment: When you ask questions about build errors, please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* output into the question. It's very likely that there's some informational notes that could help give hints about your problem or how to solve it.

Comment: The error above is all it says, I tried using point.c_str(pointx) for example and gave me the same error also

Comment: `point.c_str(pointx)` will give you a *different* error, as the `c_str` function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Can you either mark @Mannoj' answer as accepted or self-answer your question? Either will help others solve this same problem

Comment: Also note that editing headers like that is not a good idea. Better to put that define in either your own code before you include the header or make it a top-level compile flag (`-DTIXML_USE_STL`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two constructors for string/char type as below:

```
TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement (const char * _value)
```

or

```
#ifdef TIXML_USE_STL
TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement( const std::string& _value )
```

So you have to define TIXML_USE_STL if you want to use `std::string` else use `const char *`

Refer the tinyxml.cpp

Comment: @Victor J Mytre,  You can accept answer if you get help from it

Comment: I will mark this as an answer only because this actually came really useful for cleaning out my code, hopefully others coming by will read and see the way I solved in case they are doing it the same way I am. thank you

Answer (score 0):

As described, there is no matching function to `TiXmlElement(std::_cxx11::string&)` which as I understand correctly is some string class from c11 standarisation. In this case it will be exactly `point` string. Try to check if there is a way of using strings that are meant for TiXmlElement as obviously, as the error is saying, you're providing an instance of wrong class `std::_cxx11::string&`